# Superfish - Current Sub-menu Always Show

Tags: css, hide, submenu, superfish

I am using Superfish to show a horizontal menu on a website. Whenever I am on a page that is either the current menu item or sub-menu item, the sub-menu always show. When this happens, it overlaps other sub-menus when you hover the mouse over them. How do you hide the current sub-menu being shown?

edit:
OK I figured out how to do this with CSS. I added the following code to superfish-navbar.css

```
ul.sf-navbar ul {
display: none;
}
ul.sf-navbar li:hover ul {
display: block;
}
```

It hides the current sub-menu and shows all sub-menus when you hover over the parent item.

Answer (score 0):

**For CSS**

In superfish-navbar.css you would remove the following rule at line 63.

```
ul.sf-navbar .current ul, ul.sf-navbar ul li:hover ul, ul.sf-navbar ul li.sfHover ul {
      left: 0;
      top: 2.5em;
  }
```

**When You End Up Using Javascript**

In the documentation for the superfish plugin, on the Options tab, it shows the default options. It looks like pathLevels is set to 1, and the description of pathLevels

> the number of levels of submenus that remain open or are restored
>   using pathClass

looks like the option you need. Try setting pathLevels to 0.

See this jsfiddle for comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/keithwyland/G87Lm/

http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#options

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. My superfish menu doesn't even use the javascript because it is conflicting with lightbox.

Comment: "doesn't even use the javascript". but you have this script in your code:
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul.sf-menu").superfish({
animation: {opacity:'show',height:'show'}, // slide-down effect without fade-in
speed: 'fast',
pathClass: 'active',
delay: 1000 // 1.0 second delay on mouseout
});
});

Comment: Yeah, the script was there when superfish worked with javascript. I kept the script so I can use it later.

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer to have the CSS you should remove, and I left on the javascript part for your reference. Hope it helps.